# mongodb timestamp to date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i am pretty new to mongodb. i have a collection or json file like below.

```
{
  "id": {
    "timestamp": 1592538583,
    "machineIdentifier": 1772242,
    "processIdentifier": -7129,
    "counter": 2887223,
    "timeSecond": 1592538583,
    "time": 1592538583000,
    "date": 1592538583000
  },
  "creationTimestamp": 1592538583524,
  "lastUpdateTimestamp": 1592538642832,
  "idAsString": "5eec35d71b0ad2e4272c0e37"
}
```

i need to extract records based on timestamp. when i give below format its working. But i need human readable format. like lastUpdateTimestamp greater than "2020-06-30T00:00:00Z". i tried many waysbut getting bson format errors. any suggestions?

```
{ "lastUpdateTimestamp": { $gt : new Date(1592282308044) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it as a number.

```
{ "lastUpdateTimestamp": { $gt : 1592282308044 }}
```

Comment: if i give as you mentioned none of the records are coming. we need to pass with date as i mentioned in question.. but its not human readable one. users will give value as 2020-06-30.

Comment: You can convert date by this way `new Date('2020-07-30').getTime() `
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: NOTE: you should know how to use Date Class in js. as you see months start from 0 not 1 so you need to plus 1 to month.

Comment: i am getting error Improperly formatted bson string: { "lastUpdateTimestamp": { $gt : new Date('2020-06-30').getTime() }} : Date expecting integer milliseconds

Comment: I think this issue because db schema. can you use it `const schema = new Schema({
  lastUpdateTimestamp: {type:Number, default: new Date().getTime()}
});`

Comment: Improperly formatted bson string: {const schema = new Schema({   lastUpdateTimestamp: {type:Number, default: new Date().getTime()} })} : Missing colon after field name. if i give without paranthesis it gives bracket not closed error. i tried replace equals with colon. but still gives me error.

Comment: can you paste you schema to this website https://pastebin.com/ and give me url to review your schema.